# How to set disable_web_page_preview to false in Telegraf.js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

```
let itemMsg = await ctx.replyWithHTML(chosen.about, keys.actions, { disable_web_page_preview: true });
```

Bot still sends messages with link preview, how can i disable it?

I have tried

```
let itemMsg = await ctx.replyWithHTML(chosen.about, keys.actions, { disable_web_page_preview: true });
```

and

```
let itemMsg = await ctx.replyWithHTML(chosen.about, keys.actions, disable_web_page_preview = true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `disable_web_page_preview` parameter should be provided in the second parameter like this:

```js
let itemMsg = await ctx.replyWithHTML(chosen.about, {
    disable_web_page_preview: true
});
```

I am not sure what `keys.actions` object is in your code, but I believe this might work:

```js
let itemMsg = await ctx.replyWithHTML(chosen.about, {
    ...keys.action,
    disable_web_page_preview: true
});
```